# Hibernate throws UndeclaredThrowableException when i try to merge

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, merge, mapping

i have a problem when i try to merge my DashboardVO object. Everything is ok if i try to insert a new object or update (but the update i'll need to update dashboard's "perfis" and "itens" by myself).

My DashboardVO:

```
public class DashboardVO implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private int idDashboard;
   private String descricao;
   private String publico;
   private Set<DashboardPerfilVO> perfis = new HashSet<DashboardPerfilVO>();
   private Set<DashboardItemVO> itens = new HashSet<DashboardItemVO>();

public int getIdDashboard() {
    return idDashboard;
}

public void setIdDashboard(int idDashboard) {
    this.idDashboard = idDashboard;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public String getPublico() {
    return publico;
}

public void setPublico(String publico) {
    this.publico = publico;
}

public Set<DashboardPerfilVO> getPerfis() {
    return perfis;
}

public void setPerfis(Set<DashboardPerfilVO> perfis) {
    this.perfis = perfis;
}

public Set<DashboardItemVO> getItens() {
    return itens;
}

public void setItens(Set<DashboardItemVO> itens) {
    this.itens = itens;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + idDashboard;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    DashboardVO other = (DashboardVO) obj;
    if (idDashboard != other.idDashboard)
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

My DashboardVO.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="gerencial.persistencia.dashboard">
<class name="DashboardVO" table="SGT_CM_DASHBOARD">
    <id name="idDashboard" column="SEQ_DASHBOARD">   
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param       name="sequence">SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_SEQ_DASHBOARD_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>   
    <property name="descricao" column="DES_DASHBOARD" type="string"/>
    <property name="publico" column="IND_PUBLICO" type="string"/>

    <set name="perfis" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="COD_PERFIL">
        <key column="COD_DASHBOARD"/>
        <one-to-many class="DashboardPerfilVO"/>
    </set>

    <set name="itens" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="NUM_ORDEM">
        <key column="COD_DASHBOARD"/>
        <one-to-many class="DashboardItemVO"/>
    </set>

</class>
```

My method save:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ActionForward save(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws HibernateException, Exception {

    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    DashboardForm dashboardForm = (DashboardForm) form;
    Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
    DashboardVO dashboardVO;

    if (dashboardForm.getIdDashboard() == null
            || dashboardForm.getIdDashboard().equals("")) {
        dashboardVO = new DashboardVO();
    } else {
        dashboardVO = dashboard.retornaDashboard(Integer
                .parseInt(dashboardForm.getIdDashboard()));
    }
    dashboardVO.setDescricao(dashboardForm.getDescricao());
    dashboardVO.setPublico(dashboardForm.getPublico());

    Set<DashboardPerfilVO> perfis = new HashSet<DashboardPerfilVO>();
    ArrayList<DashboardPerfilVO> perfisDashboard = (ArrayList<DashboardPerfilVO>) request
            .getSession().getAttribute("perfisDashboard");

    boolean existePerfilAlterar = false;

    if (perfisDashboard != null) {
        for (DashboardPerfilVO dashboardPerfilVO : perfisDashboard) {
            if (dashboardPerfilVO.getAlterar() == 1) {
                existePerfilAlterar = true;
            }
            dashboardPerfilVO.setDashboardVO(dashboardVO);
            perfis.add(dashboardPerfilVO);
        }
    }

    if (!existePerfilAlterar) {
        // Não existe um perfil que possa alterar
        errors.add("erro", new ActionMessage(
                "erro.sem.perfil.alterar.dashboard"));
    }
    dashboardVO.setPerfis(null);
    dashboardVO.setPerfis(perfis);

    Set<DashboardItemVO> itens = new HashSet<DashboardItemVO>();

    ArrayList<DashboardItemVO> itensDashboard = (ArrayList<DashboardItemVO>) request
            .getSession().getAttribute("itensDashboard");

    if (itensDashboard == null || itensDashboard.size() < 1) {
        // Deve existir ao menos um item
        errors.add("erro", new ActionMessage("erro.sem.item.dashboard"));
    } else {
        int ordem = 0;
        for (DashboardItemVO dashboardItemVO : itensDashboard) {
            dashboardItemVO.setOrdem(++ordem);
            dashboardItemVO.setDashboardVO(dashboardVO);
            for (DashboardItemSerieVO disVO : dashboardItemVO.getSeries()) {
                disVO.setDashboardItemVO(dashboardItemVO);
            }
            itens.add(dashboardItemVO);
        }
    }
    dashboardVO.setItens(null);
    dashboardVO.setItens(itens);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

        request.setAttribute(Globals.ERROR_KEY, errors);
        return mapping.getInputForward();

    } else {

        if (dashboardForm.getIdDashboard() == null
                || dashboardForm.getIdDashboard().equals("")) {
            // Inclui o dashboard na base de dados
            dashboard.incluiDashboard(dashboardVO, sf.getCurrentSession());
            dashboardForm.setIdDashboard(String.valueOf(dashboardVO
                    .getIdDashboard()));
        } else {
            // Altera o dashboard na base de dados
            dashboard.mergeDashboard(dashboardVO, sf.getCurrentSession());
        }

        return mapping.findForward("sucesso");
    }
}
```

Before the stackTrace i get this loop (i'll post just a few rows):

```
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
Hibernate: select dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD as SEQ1_41_1_, dashboardv0_.DES_DASHBOARD as DES2_41_1_, dashboardv0_.IND_PUBLICO as IND3_41_1_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_41_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_3_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_3_, perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD as COD1_44_0_, perfis1_.COD_PERFIL as COD2_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_CONSULTAR as IND3_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_ALTERAR as IND4_44_0_, perfis1_.IND_EXCLUIR as IND5_44_0_ from SGT_CM_DASHBOARD dashboardv0_ left outer join SGT_CM_DASHBOARD_PERFIL perfis1_ on dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=perfis1_.COD_DASHBOARD where dashboardv0_.SEQ_DASHBOARD=? order by perfis1_.COD_PERFIL
```

and then i get this:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/itauditor] threw exception [java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException] with root cause java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Question 1: I want to update the DashboardVO object and its "perfis" and "itens". Should i use merge or update?  Should i update the "perfis" and "itens" first and then DashboardVO?

Question 2: Why this exception is happening? It is a mapping problem? What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I cant post full StackTrace because it's too long. There's another way i can show it?

Comment: `with root cause java.lang.StackOverflowError` how many times do you loop?

Comment: Well, I 'm not doing any loop , but when the merge method is called, begins all those selects (the selects are almost infinite), it keep going until suddenly it stops and throws the exception

Comment: At which line does it crash?

Comment: it crashes here:
        dashboardDAO.merge(dashboardVO, session);

Comment: Exactly when the session.merge is called...
public void merge(DashboardVO dashboardVO, Session session)
   throws Exception {
  session.merge(dashboardVO);
 }